# Semantic UI - queue animation

Tags: animation, meteor, frontend, semantic-ui

I'm creating web app with two other friends, we are using Meteor and Semantic UI for front end. I'm using transitions from Semantic to animate 3 columns when page is rendered. I want these three things to appear one by one.

Here is my code

```
$('.imgColumn')
.transition({
  animation : 'scale',
  duration  : 600,
  onComplete  : function(){
    $('.leftColumn')
    .transition({
      animation : 'fly right',
      duration  : 500,
      onComplete  : function(){
       $('.rightColumn')
        .transition({
          animation : 'fly left',
          duration  : 500
       });
    }
  });
}
```

});

My question is - is it a good way to do it? Is there any other solution which is better than mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using different animation types for each element, this is a perfectly fine way to handle it.

If you were trying to animate identical elements in the same way (ie. slide in one by one) you could use the interval option.

$('.jiggle.images .image')
  .transition({
    animation : 'jiggle',
    duration  : 800,
    interval  : 200
  })
;